# Is it possible to send email in nodejs to just 1 person but add other people in CC?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I have a certain use case which is not of much important in the conversation, but I want to achieve the following -

I want to be able to send emails through nodejs, the email has certain addresses in To field and certain addresses in CC. Now I want to send the email to just one person out of these To or CC people, but the data of memebers in CC and To will go along with the email.

For example I have To -  1@example.com  and CC - 2@example.com, I want to send the email to person 1 and not 2, but when person 1 opens the mail, he can see person 2 in CC.

I am looking for some kind of SMTP header i could manipulate to get the above result.

Comment: Node mailer does not support this functionality.

Comment: I think no one supports that